# Topic is not created by default in the Open Shift Kafka Instance

Tags: java, apache-kafka, openshift

I am using the below Camel Route to Produce the message to the Kafka instance, but the topic is not present in the instance. How to create the topic when it is not present in the Kafka instance?

```
@Component
public class kafkaConfig extends RouteBuilder {

  
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {


        from("timer:time")
                .to("kafka:aayush?brokers=test-hydra-cf--gejc-inbggu-ef-a.cloud.com:443&saslMechanism=PLAIN&securityProtocol=SASL_SSL&saslJaasConfig=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"...\" password=\"...\";");





    }
}
```

Output: It is saying the topic is not present.

[image]

How to create the topic when it is not present ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camel can't. That's just a plain Kafka SDK action.

Plus, you'd need to enable auto topic creation on the broker (not recommended)

With `spring-kafka`, you can define a `@Bean` to create a new topic upon application startup.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics

However, some organizations lock this down further such that only authorized services can create topics, therefore you'd need to contact your cluster administrator to create any topic.